# Installing the Cairo library for mingw to allow cross compiling for Windows

Tags: cairo, mingw32

As the title says.

I'm trying to install the cairo library for mingw so I can cross compile an application that uses it for a Windows target on my Ubuntu machine.

I can't figure out how to do it! Can someone please point me in the right direction?